# How can I make it show how much time in seconds until a specific time in python

Tags: python, canvas, time, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Im trying to make a program that shows how many seconds until a certain amount of time like (1:30am for example). Using my current code how could I accomplish this.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root.title('Timer')
root.state('zoomed')

sec = 60

def tick():
    global sec
    sec += -1
    time['text'] = sec
    time.after(1000, tick)

time = Label(root, fg='cyan')
time.pack()
btn = Button(root, fg='blue', text='Start', command=tick)
btn.pack()
btn.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.60, anchor=CENTER)
btn2 = Button(root, text='Exit', command=root.destroy)
btn2.pack()
btn2.place(relx=0.65, rely=0.60, anchor=CENTER)


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: @KlausD.       I have tried to make it run down to a specific time but it keeps giving me an error.

Answer (score 2):

lets say you have two time :

```
>>> aa = datetime.datetime(2017,4,3,15,0)
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2017,4,3,12,0)
>>> s = aa -a
>>> s
datetime.timedelta(0, 10800)
>>> s.seconds
10800
```

you can get current datetime this way :

```
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 20, 9, 32, 58, 924135)
```

Comment: If I were trying to make it set a timer for a specific time every day would I make it as a loop?

Comment: How would I also make it count down from this number (amount of seconds)

Comment: @Kg123 for count down use a for loop with time.sleep